# Can the Earth become a desert?

Tags: planets, alternate-reality

Considering that much of the surface of the Earth is covered by water, what events have to happen to turn the Earth into a desert? What would happen to water that disappears from rivers and oceans?

**EDIT**: I'm thinking a near event, in about 2000 - 4000 years.

Comment: Water is pretty much indestructible: the Earth has now just about the same amount of water it always had for the last 2 billion years. The only way to get rid of Earth's water is to blow away its atmosphere and then scorch it. The Sun will eventually do that in a few billion years. Just wait.

Comment: What time scale for the desertification of earth are you looking for?

Comment: @AlexP The earth has *more water* than 2 billion years ago. Like meteorites which increase the weight of earth several tons per day, small comets are entering continously the atmosphere and vaporize.

Comment: @ThorstenS.: That's why I said "just about". Some tiny amount of water was lost, some not so tiny but still very small amount was gained -- "just about" the same amount is present.

Comment: Actually the earth is going to have less water, even with the addition of mass from the solar system. In the last 2 billion yeas water has been integrated into minerals, disassociated by plants, and sunlight. Most of earth's mass loss is hydrogen escaping the atmosphere after having being liberated from water. This process won't dry the earth out before the sun does, no where even close, but it does result in a net loss of water.

Comment: @JoeKissling Integration into minerals or biomass does not finally lose the amount of water, it simply binds it into a chemical / biological compound and the process is reversible (and in fact water consumption/production often forms a cycle). Second while hydrogen is a component of water, it cannot be liberated easily. Only very few algae are able to produce hydrogen, the normal photosynthesis uses carbon dioxide.Also in the Hadean and Archean period (before 2 billion years) the atmosphere had relatively high hydrogen, so mineral saturation would have happened. So I am not convinced.

Comment: @ThorstenS.  In some cases, the formation of a mineral involves the dissociation of water, not just integrating water molecules into its crystal structure. Photosynthesis uses water with the carbon dioxide to produce sugars that then get integrated into the rest of the plant one way or another. Yes, quite a bit if this material makes it's way back into water, but not all resulting in a net loss. This [Study] (http://www.pnas.org/content/109/12/4371.abstract) also predicts that the oceans have lost up to a quarter of their volume due to various processes.

Comment: @JoeKissling: To be frank: I am a proponent of Louis A. Frank small comet hypothesis which claims that the majority of the water on Earth is of cometary origin and not from the mantle plume.... ;-)

Comment: ESA found the [oppsite](http://sci.esa.int/science-e-media/img/4d/ESA_Rosetta_ROSINA_DH_infographic_1280.jpg)

Comment: Using scientific but not common definition of desert - snowball earth is a place which a) fulfills definition of desert and b) there is no (liquid) water present.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The earth will be a lifeless desert in about [600 million years](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_the_far_future) as the sun get hotter near the end of its life. Ocean water will boil off and be lost to space, stripped by the heat from the sun.

**Edit: How to dry the Earth out in a few easy steps**

**Step 1:** Figure out how much energy you will need

Thanks to Wikipedia and Wolframalpha we know that the Earth has $1.4\times10^{21}$  kilograms of water on its surface and to heat to a boil and turn to steam we need $12540$ Kilojoules of energy. Also, the energy required to accelerate a kilogram of matter to escape velocity is $6.3\times10^7$ joules (The dynamics of escape are way more complex but this should be close enough). Multiply all that together and you get $1\times10^{29}$ joules to dry out the Earth, Let's add an order of magnitude to cover our bases so call it $1\times10^{30}$ joules.

**Step 2:** Figure out how fast you need it.

2000 to 4000 years? Sure thing lets just redirect some of the sun's output of $3.8\times10^{26}$ Watts of energy towards the earth using the following equation.

$T_{dry} = \frac{1\times10^{30}\text{Joules}}{3.8\times10^{26}\text{watts} \times \%\text{ sun output}}$

Now thermodynamics is tricky as we heat the earth it's going to radiate some of the heat away and slow down out drying of the planet. So we should deliver the energy much more quickly and for longer, how much I can't say but a factor of 4 should be a good place to start. So if we focus $1.8\times10^{-6}$ percent of the sun's energy on the earth we will deliver all the energy we need to get rid of the water in about 500 years. Cook for a good 2000 to 4000 years and should have gotten rid of all the water on the planet. *On, not in the planet.*

**Step 3:** Construct a Dyson swarm out of the planet mercury and get to it!

**Congratulations!** You have succeeded in removing all water on earth, probably the atmosphere too, and maybe even [halted plate tectonics](http://records.viu.ca/~earles/subduction-water-oct01.htm). The earth may have been rendered sterile too.*

*Results may [vary](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/life-found-deep-inside-earths-oceanic-crust/)

Comment: I'm thinking in an event in about 2000 - 3000 years

Answer (score 3):

You have various possibilities:

1. **Sun reaches end of its life**. While expanding its outer layer swallow the inner planets, Earth included. This will vaporize not only the oceans, but the entire planet.
2. **Raging green house effect** (Venus-like scenario). First oceans will boil and water would only be present as vapor, then, as water vapor is a much stronger greenhouse agent than CO$_2$, the temperature might rise further, breaking the water molecule into hydrogen and oxygen. Hydrogen would then slowly leack to space.
3. **Earth magnetic field vanishes** (Mars-like scenario). With nothing to shield it, the solar wind starts peeling off the atmosphere. With pressure going down, evaporation rate increases until a much slimmer layer remains.

Comment: Water is a greenhouse gas all the way up to forming clouds. Then, the effect of water vapour suddenly becomes cooling. And there is always cold enough atmpsphere layer where the water will condense. Venus-like scenario requires a surface hot enough to decompose carbonates. Venus probably never got below that point.

Answer (score 2):

> Can the Earth become a desert?

Not without a major catastrophic event, in the sense of water disappearing entirely.

A collision with another planet or something like that which melts the whole planet would do it perhaps.

But the same thing could be achieved just by removing liquid water, life needs liquid water. There are many deserts that get covered in snow but only rarely have actual usable water for plants to absorb, therefore they're deserts. So too hot or too cold could be an Ice Age or greenhouse going crazy.

Answer (score 2):

Humans build a space elevator with an [Archimedes Screw](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes%27_screw) running through it to lift water into space. Why? No idea. We are human. Maybe it is part of us relocating. Maybe we are selling water to aliens. Maybe it is an art project.

Anyway, the screw turns and begins lifting water to space. A 5-meter wide pipe with a 500kW engine like a typical car can lift 1.45 m^3/sec. Given the volume of Earth's oceans as 1.338e9 km^3 (notice that's km and the other was just m), it would take 9.22e16 years. Better just wait for the sun at that rate.

We can do better.

[This presentation](https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/sjmiller/public_html/hudson/Shappy_Archimedean.pdf) lays out all the math. Way more than I care to do, but you might want to. Or [this excellent paper](http://cicada.cs.drexel.edu/~crorres/screw/screw.pdf). They're both straightforward algebra.

2014 saw [installation in the Netherlands of the world's largest Archimedes Screw to date](http://wwtonline.co.uk/news/record-breaking-pumps-ordered-for-hull)... capable of 4 m^3 /sec. Four! Wow. Um... yeah... that's not going to put much of a dent in that 9.22e16 number. Even running several in parallel won't help much.

The Screw is a pretty efficient pump and one of the few that can lift the distance needed to space. I doubt you can do better with human tech, both known and imagined under known physics. Oceans are big!

Comment: If you have a general space elevator, you can use it to carry loads of water.

Comment: @jdlugosz sure, but a continuous pump up the elevator will outperform any given pack-and-lift system. If we can't get that ocean lifted with a screwpump in reasonable time, I don't think anything else accelerates it.